# Google MX check bogus error? Every name server must reply with exactly the same TXT records

Tags: dns, spf

was using this tool, https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/checkmx/, to check my domain and it reports this error:

```
Every name server must reply with exactly the same TXT records.
```

my domain has multiple TXT records and a *dig* check verified that all the name servers respond with all of the TXT records, but not in the same order. otherwise the records are exact matches. in fact the tools itself shows the records and they are exactly the same. so the response order must be the trigger here.

but is that really an error? doesn't seem right.

Comment: same happening to me while trying to setup SPF record (to enable DMARC)

Comment: Same error, and their tool is showing me the results of their tests, and they are all identical!

Comment: @race_carr (and rvh) have you ever managed to find an answer / resolution to this?
I have removed all TXT record but the SPF, the google tool says the is a problem because they all need to be identical but shows all of the results to be the same.

Which DNS provider are you using? I read people having using GoDaddy DNS having the same issue, I use he.net.

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/381016-google-apps-dns-issues

Comment: I did fix it (no longer get that warning) but honestly I have no memory of what exactly I did to fix it

Answer (score 2):

The issue has to do with DNS. I have moved the domain I was having a problem with to a different DNS provider and it fixed the issue.

Beside gmail, there was no issue with the previous DNS provider, I ran several tests from DNS test sites as well as manual tests, and none showed any error or issue. It looks like this problems comes from how gmail/google do their DNS tests. The only difference between the two DNS providers is how to reply to ANY queries, the original one (the one gmail had a problem with), replied with every records for the domain apex, including the TXT records, but the one I moved to (the one gmail had no problem with) replies with NS records only.

For reference, this is a long thread with other people with the same issue on a google forum, but with unfortunately no firm answer: https://support.google.com/mail/thread/12094094